# Setting custom font without specific size for title of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try **titleTextAttributes** for setting custom Font on UINavigationBar. It required to set a specific font size tor the title.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *CambriaFont = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Cambria" size:20.0] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    self.MyNavigationBar.titleTextAttributes = CambriaFont;
```

Is there any setting for load custom font on UINavigationBar **without define the font size**, instead its size will automatically fit to UINavigationBar size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, UINavigationBar requires a font with a size. If you want the font to scale under certain circumstances you need to manually calculate the new font size and replace the `titleTextAttributes` value with the new font.

Comment: Thanks Nima. I find out UINavigationBar has fix height so no matter if I set font size appropriately with Bar height.